# Can not get /route after refresh page Angular 7

Tags: angular, server, routes, live

I have a few components in Angular 7, and I don't use 'useHash: true' for routing.

I deployed my Angular app on live server, if I navigate to some component using routing (for example /panel) then it is working properly, but if I reload that page I get error 'Can not get /panel'

Could anyone help with this ?

Comment: set base path in index.html to your root project folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your server to fallback to index.html.
Check at angular docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration) how you can do this.
On Appcache server for example I am using this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this CLI command in your app

```
ng build --prod="true" --base-href="<Your-Base-Path/<your-project-folder-name>"
```

and, this will set base path in `index.html` with your defined path, so every time when you refresh page it will at base of your Root folder.

Now your `index.html` file has this `base-path`

```
<base href="<Your-Base-Path/<your-project-folder-name>">
```

Comment: ng build --prod="true" --base-href="<Your-Base-Path/<your-project-folder-name>"

This command didn't help me